# Accented characters have wrong width in pdf() device

Tags: r, pdf

I am trying to generate PDF in R which would support Czech accented characters:

```
encoding <- "CP1250.enc"
pdf(file = paste0("tmp-", encoding, ".pdf"), width = 4, height = 4, encoding = encoding, colormodel = "cmyk")
plot(1,1, main = "ěščřžýáíéúů,ďňóť")
dev.off()
```

Unfortunatelly, there is incorrect spacing of the accented letters, as shown on the image below. How do I fix this? Using `cairo_pdf` works in this one regard, but I need the CMYK colorspace which Cairo doesn't support (despite [a great work of Andrea Canciani](https://core.ac.uk/display/14701464) which has been done more than 10 years ago). **I guess there must be a way how to make this work with the basic pdf() device?**

[image]

My encoding is CP1250 (on Windows 10):

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Czech_Czechia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Czech_Czechia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Czech_Czechia.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Czech_Czechia.1250
```

But I tried all available encodings with no result.

Comment: The issue is the font. It displays correctly if I specify `family = "ArialMT"`. Other fonts might work too but many fonts don't contain Czech characters.

Comment: @Roland, wow, works for me too, thanks! How did you find this one? I don't have any `ArialMT*.ttf` file in `C:\Windows\Fonts\`. Do you know how does this work and what does "MT" mean? Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but spacing issues hint at an issue with the font and not with the encoding. The documentation regarding fonts for use within `pdf` is, let's say, not easy to understand for non-experts. It was therefore not easy for me to find good alternative fonts that might work. Fortunately, Google found [an old version](http://math.furman.edu/%7Edcs/courses/math47/R/library/grDevices/html/postscript.html) of `help("postscript")` that mentions [.afm files](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/tree/master/src/library/grDevices/inst/afm) in package grDevices. Trying the first font fixed the issue:

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = "Czech_Czechia.1250")
encoding <- "CP1250.enc"

pdf(file = paste0("E:/temp/tmp-", encoding, ".pdf"), 
    width = 4, height = 4, colormodel = "cmyk", encoding = encoding, family = "ArialMT")
plot(1,1, main = "ěščřžýáíéúů,ďňóť")
dev.off()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Some other fonts might also work.

Comment: Thank you! I would love a general answer independent on font of course, because I will need to use different fonts in the future. But this fixes the issue for now and gives me some guidance. Thanks! :)

Comment: ... interesting question is, how can Cairo guarantee well displayed accents for any font? Could this be done with pdf() device as well? :-)

Comment: @Tomas Another option could be to try and embed the font in the PDF. I didn't try that route because it appears to involve ghostscript and I'm not sure that's set up on my system. I'm not sure it would help but might be worth investigating.